# How to select (connect with) multiples tables in Joomla database / Seblod

Tags: php, mysql, database, joomla3.0

I've created a form using the component SEBLOD for joomla, it's all right, I can properly view the data entered, but i would like to manipulate the data, however I am not able to connect to the database, so I tried this:

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;


$catId = 11;
$catId2 = 12;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM #__cck_store_form_add_compras";
$con = &JFactory::getDBO();
$con->setQuery($sql);
$resultado = $con->loadObjectList();


$query = "SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE catid ='" . $catId . "' OR catid ='" .  $catId2 . "'";
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery($query);
$articles = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach($articles as $article){
echo '<br/><br/>ID:'. $article->id
.'<br/>Titulo: '. $article->title
.'<br/>Quantidade Comprada: '.$resultado[0]->add_compras_quantidade_comprada
.'<br/>Unidade de Medida: '.$resultado[0]->add_compras_unidade_de_medida
.'<br/>Preço Por Kilo/Unidade: '.$resultado[0]->add_compras_preco_por_unidade_kilo
.'<br/>Data da Compra: '.$resultado[0]->add_compras_data_da_compra
.'<br/>Total da Compra: '.$resultado[0]->add_compras_total_da_compra
.'<br/>Local da Compra: '.$resultado[0]->add_compras_local_da_compra
;
}
?>
```

What I want is to get the id of the article, article name, article category that are saved in the table #__content, and the other fields that are saved in the table #__cck_store_form_add_compras, but only articles with category id = 11 or category id = 12

When i use this code (above) I see the results however some of them appears repeated.

.

When i use this below, i see only the id of article and article name, but i cant see the other fields:

```
$catId = 11;
$catId2 = 12;
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE catid ='" . $catId . "' OR catid ='" . $catId2 . "'";
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery($query); 
$articles = $db->loadObjectList();
```

.

if i use the code below, i can see only other fields, but i can't see the id of article and name of article:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM #__cck_store_form_add_compras";
$con = &JFactory::getDBO();
$con->setQuery($sql);
$resultado = $con->loadObjectList();
```

.

looking at the documentation I found this piece of code:

```
// Get a db connection.
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

// Select all articles for users who have a username which starts with 'a'.
// Order it by the created date.
// Note by putting 'a' as a second parameter will generate `#__content` AS `a`
$query
 ->select($db->quoteName(array('a.*', 'b.username', 'b.name')))
 ->from($db->quoteName('#__content', 'a'))
 ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__users', 'b') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('a.created_by') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('b.id') . ')')
 ->where($db->quoteName('b.username') . ' LIKE \'a%\'')
 ->order($db->quoteName('a.created') . ' DESC');

// Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
$db->setQuery($query);

// Load the results as a list of stdClass objects (see later for more options on retrieving data).
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

I think it's exactly what I need, but i don't know how can I change to that fits my needs, someone could help me?

Sorry for my bad english, I'm using google translator to help me.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to display a filtered list of SEBLOD contents is to use a SEBLOD search and display it through a menu item, a module or inside a SEBLOD content (use a CCK module or CCK list field).
In your SEBLOD search, you can set the 'article category id' as filter with "11,12" as default value so only articles in these 2 categories will be retrieved.

Please find the full answer to your question on SEBLOD forums http://www.seblod.com/community/forums/general-discussions/connecting-to-database#post22181

Thanks.
Sebastien.

Answer (score 0):

With JTable::getInstance("content"); you may get data from Joomla content table and leave SEBLOD content for the query.

Example:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__cck_store_form_produto";
$db = &JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery($query);
$values = $db->loadObjectList();
foreach($values as $val){

echo $val->id; // The article ID is inside SEBLOD table too.
echo $val->your_field; // will write the value on a SEBLOD field called "your_field"

// now to get joomla values 

$maindata =& JTable::getInstance("content");
$maindata->load($val->id);

echo $maindata->title; //will write article title
echo $maindata->alias; //will write article alias
echo $maindata->catid; //will write article Category ID

}
```

Or you can also use "INNER JOIN" between two tables just use the ID to link the values:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp